# How to resolve Mongokit TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'collection' error

Tags: python, mongokit

My code looks like:

```
class DocumentLog(MongokitBaseModel):
    __collection__ = 'document_log'
    __database__ = MASTER_DB


db = connection.DocumentLog(dData)
```

How to resolve Mongokit TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'collection' error

Comment: Show more code, please.